# How to make Python runtime error more verbose?

Tags: python, error-handling, runtime

I am running a block of code that raises a runtime warning and continues to run until the end.

> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:14: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars

I would like the behavior in case of "divide by zero" to be halting the program and telling me exactly where it stopped with the full stack. How do I force this to happen?

Comment: There is most likely a `try`/`except`/`finally` that catches the exception.

Comment: It says line 14 and gives the file. What is missing?

Comment: @BaileyKocin The rest of the stack. What caused line 14 of that file to be called?

Comment: If you wrap it in a try catch that is all you will get because the exception will not propagate up the stack. Do you have sonetjing catching that error? Or is something else going on?

Comment: @KlausD. Do you mean adding `try/catch` to my code? This would mean `try/catching` every single line to find the problem. If there were a way to automatically get the line that caused the problem, that would save me a lot of time.

Comment: @BaileyKocin I assume one of the libraries that I am using catches the error somewhere, but if I could force warnings to halt the program the same way an error does, that would be of great help.